# how to pass a variable through sendKeys in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I want to pass the float variable 'f' through sendKeys in the below program.Can someone please let me know the same? As of now, it is throwing

> "The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments ".

**Code:**

```
public static String isEditable(String s1) {
    f=Float.parseFloat(s1);
    System.out.println(f);

    boolean bool=webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression")).isEnabled();
    if(bool) {
        if((f<0) || (f>6)) {
            error="Value must be between 0.00% and 6.00%";
            System.out.println(error);
        } else {
            webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(""expression")).sendKeys(f);
        }
    } else {
        error="Please enter a valid Number";
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: or is there any other way to pass that variable in to the eit box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the float to a string:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys(Float.toString(f));
```

Comment: @Raghu You should use the String `s1` directly like mentioned below. There is no reason to parse it back again. So instead of  `sendKeys(Float.toString(f))` use `sendKeys(s1)`...

Comment: Yes d0x, that will also work.:)But to continue the flow for user readibility, I wanted f to passed as string.Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing `s1` instead of `f`. Because the method takes a string, not a float.

Your method should look like this:

```
String selector = "expression";
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(selector)).sendKeys(f);
```

And please use better variable names like `userInput` instead of `s1` or `userInputAsFloat` instead of `f` or `investmentInputVisible` instead of `bool` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but I wanted to clean up your code a little and give you some feedback.

1. I changed the name of the function because a function named `isEditable()` should return a `boolean` indicating whether some field is editable. That's not what your function is doing so it should be given a more appropriate name. I made a guess at what the actual name should be... I could be way off but you should name it something more along the lines of what it's actually doing... putting text in a field.
2. I removed the `isEnabled()` check because that should be done in the function that sets the fund number. Each function should do one thing and only one thing. This function validates that the rate passed is in a valid range and then puts it in the field.
3. I removed the duplicate code that was scraping the INPUT twice. Just do it once, save it in a variable, and reuse that variable. In this case, there's no need to scrape it twice.
4. and as d0x said, you shouldn't convert the `s1` string to a `float` and then back to `string` when you `sendKeys()` ... just send the `s1` string. Translating it back doesn't help readability, it just means you wrote more code that someone after you will need to understand. Favor clean code... it's always more readable.

   ```
   public static String enterRate(String s1)
   {
       f = Float.parseFloat(s1);
       WebElement input = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='p_InvestmentSelection_4113']/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li/div[3]/div[2]/label/div[1]/input"));
       if ((f < 0) || (f > 6))
       {
           error = "Value must be between 0.00% and 6.00%";
       }
       else
       {
           input.sendKeys(s1);
       }
       return error;
   }
   ```

Comment: I have learnt something from your feedback.Thankyou !!                                               However, I understand that the requirement is not clear to you. Here it is,  whenever a valid fund number is entered, the salescharge field should get enabled. So, the logic is to check whether the salesCharge field is enabled or not and then enter the value accordingly.Again there is valdiation for min. n max values. So, the error is thrown out accordingly. Hope it is clear now.