# Inserting values into a text fields using automation - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have logged into a website page using automation code (Selenium) but now there are fields in which data needs to be entered 
But how to do this using Selenium?
How to write the code for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass a variable through sendKeys in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563054/how-to-pass-a-variable-through-sendkeys-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Use sendKeys method.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("InputBox_ID")).sendKeys("Test data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following lines of code to insert value into text.

```
    WebElement Element1 = driver.findElementByName("abc");
    Element1.sendKeys("value that you want to enter.");
```

Answer (score 0):

When searching for a field to fill in, right click on its element in the web page and click "Inspect Element". The ID should be highlighted in the popup menu, and that is going to be the ID You specify into the "By.xpath()" Method from seleniums API.

Here is an example on how to fill in fields for Gmail.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(Links.Register_Gmail);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys(firstname);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys(lastname);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='GmailAddress']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='PasswdAgain']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthMonth']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':" + random(1, 9) + "']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthDay']")).sendKeys("" + random(1, 27));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthYear']")).sendKeys("" + random(1950, 1990));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Gender']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':f']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submitbutton']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tos-scroll-button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tos-scroll-button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tos-scroll-button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='iagreebutton']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply by just right click on the field that you want to fill and click inspect, if you are using firefox then it is quiet simple by using firepath but if you are using chrome then simply right click on the field, click on inspect element and find a unique id of that field and put it inside these below lines 
driver.findelement(By.id("")).sendelement(""),
you can use different field than id if you find something else unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method and call it wherever you want to enter text

```
public static void enterTextInput(WebElement element, String value) throws InterruptedException{
    String val = value; 
    element.clear();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++){
        char c = val.charAt(i);
        String str = new StringBuilder().append(c).toString();
        element.sendKeys(str);
    }   
    Thread.sleep(1500);
}
```